# Path class alternative to __file__ in python

Tags: python

Each python script has its own `__file__` property, which is `str` with the path to this script.

Since there is a `pathlib.Path` class, is there any corresponding alternative to `__file__`? Like `__file_path__` such that `type(__file_path__) == Path`?

Is it true that the closest we can have to this is to just use `Path(__file__)` instead of `__file__`?

Comment: AFAIK, that's it.

Comment: Since `Path` isn't a built-in type, the low-level Python interpreter doesn't depend on it, so it doesn't create a property like that automatically.

Comment: by "built-in" type, I think @Barmar means that it's not implemented via C code in the `Objects` direction in the CPython source. e.g., `int` is implement in [Objects/longobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c), but see `vars(__builtins__)` at the repl or https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/builtins.html for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__file__` and similar attributes are [set by the import machinery](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes). All these attribute use the `str` type to describe paths.

In order to treat these paths as `Path` instances, the simplest option is to convert them explicitly, for example as `pathlib.Path(__file__)`, when needed.